# How to change values only in HTML snippet in VS code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

Do you know is there a way to change values only from code HTML code snippets?
You can see an example of snippet below but the real ones will be with more values and editing the values directly in code hide some risks.

Is there any way to preview and edit there the values, something like Dreamweaver Code/Design preview functionality or any other way to easy and fast change only the numbers?

Example for snippet:

```
    <div class="plan">
    <h3>Basic<span>$9</span></h3>
    <a class="signup" href="">Sign up</a>       
    <ul>
        <li><b>1GB</b> Disk Space</li>
        <li><b>10GB</b> Monthly Bandwidth</li>
        <li><b>2</b> Email Accounts</li>
        <li><b>Unlimited</b> subdomains</li>            
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own snippets in VSCode. Go take a look at this page and see how to create one. [Creating your own snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_creating-your-own-snippets)

Comment: Not sure that this helps because still there is no easy way to fast changing the values

Comment: You can create you snippet code and just fill it out whenever and wherever you want. I think this is easy to do.